# Hide context menu without disabling text selection

Tags: android

The goal is to show a custom context menu, on top of the selected text. 
Tried clearing the menu items in onSupportActionModeStarted:

```
@Override
public void onSupportActionModeStarted(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode) {
    super.onSupportActionModeStarted(mode);
    mode.getMenu().clear();
    mode.getMenu().close();

}
```

but the context menu is still showing with a blank background and back button and with no items inside

I tried setting `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>` to the AppTheme but to no avail.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this way?
    
    `@Override
    public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
        super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
        mode.getMenu().clear();
        mode.getMenu().close();
    }`

I have made without support and worked. It have not needed:
    
`<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>`

Remember to implement this in one activity.